# Cpanel - setup cron job to run after a specific time

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

I have gone through many questions and answers to find out the answer for this, but none of them apparently helped me and finally I thought to put it as a question.

I'm fairly new to cron jobs, and by now I know how to set up a cron job to run every 15 minutes (or given interval).

But now, I want a cron job to be run every 15 minutes on every Sunday, **but after 10 AM** (because i have set up some other scripts to run before 10 AM, and this one need to have those run before.)

My current setup : `0   0   *   *   0`

any help is appreciated. I would prefer to do it using cpanel as I have no any other access to server.

thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea if cpanel affects this at all but a setup like

```
*/15    10-24   *   *   0
```

should run every Sunday, at 15 minutes interval, between 10AM and Midnight.

EDIT: corrected as per comment.

Comment: */15 10-24 * * 0 for all x min = */x

Comment: here is already 10 AM :) cpanel documentation says: "In the Command field, type the command you wish the system to run" (http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/CronJobs) so it should work.

Comment: because Penalty Shootout #ARGvsNED #dontTellTheBoss